# Error ORA-00054 resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired in oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I'm using oracle11g database. I have a table in the name of `phonenumbers_tbl` and I performed the `DROP` command on that table. But It is returning the error `resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired`. After that I was alter the session with the command `alter session set ddl_lock_timeout = 600` and Again try to drop the table. But still This error is persisting again

Answer (score 3):

Try to execute this first ,and check whether anyone from `other session` or `your session` put a lock on that table .If `you` have put a lock on that table,try to do `commit/rollback` .If `someone else` put a lock ,ask `him/her` or if you have rights `kill his session` .And then drop the table.

```
           select session_id "sid",SERIAL#  "Serial",
    substr(object_name,1,20) "Object",
      substr(os_user_name,1,10) "Terminal",
      substr(oracle_username,1,10) "Locker",
      nvl(lockwait,'active') "Wait",
      decode(locked_mode,
        2, 'row share',
        3, 'row exclusive',
        4, 'share',
        5, 'share row exclusive',
        6, 'exclusive',  'unknown') "Lockmode",
      OBJECT_TYPE "Type"
    FROM
      SYS.V_$LOCKED_OBJECT A,
      SYS.ALL_OBJECTS B,
      SYS.V_$SESSION c
    WHERE
      A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID AND
      C.SID = A.SESSION_ID
    ORDER BY 1 ASC, 5 Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

yes ! finally I got a solution that is moved the table `phonenumber_tbl` to another tablespace `system` and dropped the table.

Comment: :Thats not the solution,its an alternative :),please try to find out why this was giving you nowait error.

Answer (score 1):

At first get table lock session then kill session
SELECT a.sid,a.serial#, a.username,c.os_user_name,a.terminal,
b.object_id,substr(b.object_name,1,40) object_name
from v$session a, dba_objects b, v$locked_object c
where a.sid = c.session_id
and b.object_id = c.object_id;

ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#' ;

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the follow code:

```sql
select c.owner, c.object_name, c.object_type,b.sid, b.serial#, b.status
from gv$locked_object a , gv$session b, dba_objects c
where b.sid = a.session_id
and a.object_id = c.object_id;
```